# Buttons not resizing correctly in Landscape mode (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

```
<Grid x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <Button x:Name="ButtonOne" Content="ButtonOne" IsEnabled="False" Click="ButtonOne_Click" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonTwo" Content="ButtonTwo" IsEnabled="False" Click="ButtonTwo_Click" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

This is the XAML code I have. I would like to have the two buttons on the same row and of the same width. Right now, though, the two buttons are one on top of the other. Setting the button column doesn't seem to be enough, what else did I forget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have defined any column definitions on your grid.

Try this -

```
<Grid x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonOne" Content="ButtonOne" IsEnabled="False" Click="ButtonOne_Click" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonTwo" Content="ButtonTwo" IsEnabled="False" Click="ButtonTwo_Click" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! There is a typo in the second `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>`, it should be `</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>` though ;)